# In IE 11 = is not working trying to assign object to another object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to assign an object to another object but it is not happening in IE11

My code looks like this.

```
$('.nodoc:first').on('change',function(){
  var FirstSelectedFilePath = this.files;
  var SelectedDate = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.Emptyclient').val();
  $('.nodoc').each(function (i, element){
      var presentDate = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.Emptyclient').val();
    if (element.value == '' && SelectedDate == presentDate) {
      element.files = FirstSelectedFilePath;
    }else{}
  })
})
```

the file is an input type = "file". which i am trying to assign to another input file type. it is working fine in chrome an firefox but not in IE.

What i observed is the below one is not happening in IE11 it passing into the if condition but the assignment is not happening.

```
element.files = FirstSelectedFilePath;
```

Is there any another alternative way or work around?

Comment: var FirstSelectedFilePath = $(this).files;

Comment: i'm assigning the object in an variable. is that what you want to know or some thing else @Zaid Bin Khalid

Comment: _Is there any another alternative way or work around?_  jquery `data`

Comment: Hi  Chay22 i mean to ask is there any wrong in my approach if it is right it is not working in IE11. so can you suggest any other alternative way? either JS or Jquery. End result should work in all the browsers.